# UITextField Currency Format Left to Right

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, number-formatting

I want to format my UITextField with having a `$` on the left when I enter an amount.

So far what my code does is when I enter let says `$5.65` this is how it's entered: `$0.05` -> `$0.56` -> `$5.65`

I want it so that it's not right to left but left to right so something like this: `$5` -> `$5.` -> `$5.6` -> `$5.65`

But I want to restrict it to only two decimals place, the dollar sign is on the left, and you can not type any other characters (e.g: !,@,#,$,%,^, A-Z')

This is what I have currently:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let text: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let finalString = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    // 'currency' is a String extension that doews all the number styling
    amuTextField.text = finalString.currency

    // returning 'false' so that textfield will not be updated here, instead from styling extension
    return false
}

func currencyInputFormatting() -> String {

    var number: NSNumber!
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
    formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

    var amountWithPrefix = self

    // remove from String: "$", ".", ","
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
    amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

    let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
    number = NSNumber(value: (double / 100))

    return formatter.string(from: number)!
}
```

Comment: You'll probably get most of what you want simply be removing the `/ 100`.

Comment: I took away the `/ 100` and changed the min and Max fraction digit to 0 and got close but I can't add a decimal

Comment: You'll probably need a special check that if the current string ends in `.` then after formatting it, add back the `.` to the end of the result.

Comment: Could you show me an example on how I should approach that with my current functions and variables

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to limit the decimal places after the `.`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

      guard let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
        return true
      }

      let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
      let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
      let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

      let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
      if let dotIndex = newText.firstIndex(of: ".") {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
      } else {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
      }

      return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
  }
```